# Converting a JSON String to a class when the class does not use all properties provided by the JSON string

Tags: c#, .net, json, list

I'm trying to figure out how to parse the following JSON string

```
[
  {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Johnny"
     "dob": "12/10/1986"
     "sex": "Male"
  },
  {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "Sarah"
     "dob": "3/7/1979"
     "sex": "Female"
  }
]
```

The class I am trying to read it into is a list of class person which only has the variables name, dob and sex. Is there a way that is as simple to do this as it is if the class also contained id and so could just be deserialized straight into the list?

i tried looking through the other similar questions although none seem to include this aspect of not requiring some the properties appearing in the JSON string.

Comment: You can still deserialize to your person class. It will just ignore the id in the JSON

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can still deserialize to your person class.

Assuming

```
public class Person {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string dob { get; set; }
    public string sex { get; set; }
}
```

It will just ignore the `id` in the JSON when desrializing.

For example, using the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) package.

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsonIgnore] attribute over the attribute if you want to ignore it